# Use timer to execute script every 10 seconds in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, timer

I have a script that I want to execute automatically every ten seconds indefinitely until I tell it to stop. The script is called 'KelEdge'. I tried to figure out the code but I am having difficulty. Here is what I have:

```
function t = autoVIX()
t = timer;
t.StartFcn = @autoVIXstart;
t.TimerFcn = @runKelEdge;
t.StopFcn = @autoVIXCleanup;
t.Period = 10;
t.TasksToExecute = inf;
t.ExecutionMode = 'fixedRate';
end 
function autoVIXstart(KelEdge,~)
KelEdge;
end
function runKelEdge(KelEdge,~)
KelEdge;
end
function autoVIXCleanup(KelEdge,~)
disp('Stopping KelEdge.')
delete(KelEdge)
end
```

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: What difficulty are you having? What is your question?

Comment: I run the above script then type start(t) in the command window and get the output below:

Error while evaluating TimerFcn for timer 'timer-3' 

Attempt to add "now" to a static workspace.
 See Variables in Nested and Anonymous Functions.

Comment: Add it to the question! Can you provide a [mcve]?